# performance counter missing in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: performance

user defined performance counter missing from performance monitor but performance entry exist in the registry with all information like Dll and open,collect and close functions.
I tried lodctr /r and exctrlst.exe also shows my counter enabled.

any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

might be related to the windows account that your program runs as. I had an similar problem, windows perfmon can show my customized counters if i run my program in LocalSystem account while not show them if i run it in another account.